# "window.location.history.go(-2)" possible in major browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, security, internet-explorer, browser

As the title says, will this code work and will it work in major browsers?

I ask because currently I have no resources to test it, so I would appreciate some help on this.

Here is what I have (not tested):

```
setTimeout(window.location.history.go(-2), 5000);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
setTimeout(window.location.history.go(-2), 5000);
```

`history` is a property of `window`, not `location`. Also if you want it to trigger after a delay you will need to make a delayed-call function—currently you are calling `go()` immediately, and passing the return value of the function to `setTimeout`, which clearly won't work. You probably mean:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    history.go(-2);
}, 5000);
```

As for ‘go back two pages’, yes, it'll work in pretty much all JS-supporting browsers, but it's the kind of thing users are likely to find incredibly confusing. Are you sure you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

as you can see [here](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/history.htm#go) this is supported by all browsers for a long time (since ff1.0 / opera 5 / ie 3).

Comment: Should I have double-quotes around the window.location?

Answer (score 0):

It works on Netscape 2.0+, IE3+, Opera 5.12+, Firefox 1+, Konquerer 3.1+, Safari 1+.
You just have to be sure, there are at least so many sites in the history, you want to go back.

[German reference on SELFHTML](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/history.htm#go)

Answer (score 0):

It has been around since the first version of JavaScript, so it's universally supported. Please note, though, that your code will not work as it currently is because you're calling `go` *now*, and passing the result of the function as the function reference. Also, it's just `history`, not `location.history`. Try this instead:

```
setTimeout(function() { history.go(-2); }, 5000);
```

Comment: Have tested it just now, didn't happen anything. Hmm